# Unit testing angular.extend function with jasmine spyOn

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a directive, where, in certain case I use

```
angular.extend(dist, src)
```

Now I would like to test this case and check, if angular.extend is called.

I'm trying to use spyOn

```
spyOn(angular, 'extend')
```

And then in test

```
expect(angular.extend).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Not sure I can do it at all, but I decided to give it a try.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Here is my test, edited in accordance with your advise.

```
it('should create new scope and extend config if config is passed to directive', function() {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('extendSpy').and.callThrough();
    angular.extend = spy;
    timeout.flush();
    _.forEach(scope.accordionConfig, function(configItem) {
        if (configItem.config) {
            expect(angular.extend).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }
    });
});
```

In beforeEach hook I don't have anything special, just assigning config, creating some other preparation for rest tests and compiling the directive.

Here is a snippet from link function which I'm trying to test

```
if (scope.format === 'directive') {
    if (scope.config) {
        newScope = $rootScope.$new();
        angular.extend(newScope, scope.config);
    }
    scope.content = $compile(scope.content)(newScope || scope);
}
```

Comment: Looks legit overall.
You might want to use `toHaveBeenCalledWith(dist, src)` to assert also the argument of the invocation.
And chain `andCallThrough()` if other parts of the function that are being tested depend on the outcome of `extend`

Comment: Actually, I would be glad to use suggested options, but test keep failing. I assume that angular.extend is not called.. At least not that instance of angular.. if it can be possible

Answer (score 0):

console log the value of angular.extend before the assertion, it should be an instance of `jasmine.spy`, if it is not, there is a problem in the way that you create the spy, and we will need more context, perhaps your full code could help.
I assume you create the hook somewhere in the `beforeEach` hook or on one of the other hooks?

Try the following code:

```
var spy = jasmine.createSpy('extendSpy').and.callThrough();
angular.extend = spy;
expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(dist, src);
```

Comment: If I do console.log(angular.extend) before assertion, I have a function, not jasmine.spy instance. Yes, I have beforeEach hooks. Let me try create spy in the test itself

Comment: didn't work.. console.log gives me this: LOG: function () { ... }

Comment: if you need anything else from my code, just write. Actually, not sure what you may need, because I create similar spies and everything works great, except this one

Comment: answer edited.
Please consider posting the full code if this does not help.

Comment: It didn't work, but interesting thing, that console.log(spy) gives me also LOG: functoin() { ... } I would like to go in chat for further discussion

Comment: But not sure how to do this until we make a lot of comments)

Comment: few further suggestions:
Try to assert against the `spy` variable and not against `angular.extend`, although they hold the same reference.
Try to use the `done` callback to indicate that the test is complete, since it seems that there is some asynchronous logic that happens there.

Comment: I did it in different way. Actually what I've tried to do originally wasn't solved, but I gave up, because I had to move forward. Any way thanks for trying! I appreciate it.